# Better app UI when site is down for maintenance

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Earlier today, Stack Exchange went down for a period of time due to a routing issue. At the time, I was browsing on my iPhone via the native app, and suddenly my connections were timing out, as indicated by the black stripe above the table view. As I thought it was an error on my end, I immediately sprang to check my connection to other sites. As I came to realize though, the network was just down for maintenance on the routing issue and would be back up momentarily. Then I realized: at this point, there is not much distinguishing a local network error from an error/maintenance period on the site.

**Is there any way we can have a more obvious way of detecting the site is down for maintenance and not simply *down*** from the mobile app? It's not imperative, just something that would be nice to have.

Comment: Nothing to do with read-only mode. The site was _totally down and inaccessible_ for a while a few hours ago and _could not be connected to._ The Android app didn't have any way to handle this, and simply froze and crashed.